Proving $(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{i})^2=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)x^n$
We are trying to evaluate:
$$\sum_{i=0,j=0}^{\infty}x^{i+j}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)x^n$$
My attempt:
$$\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty x^{i+j}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^{i+j}$$
And obviously, the coefficient for $x^n$ would be all positive integral solutions: $i+j=n$
And that would be $i=0,1,2,\cdots ,n$.
Therefore we can conclude that the infinite series we're trying to evaluate is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n$.
I encountered this calculation in Polya's Problems and Theorems in Analysis, without a proof. However, I think my evaluation is somehow unrigorous. Any more ideas?

I have since asked a question about the generalized result of this
General Case

Both are equal $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} , \quad |x|<1.$$

Your method is perfectly fine. The sum $\sum_{i\geq 0, \ j\geq 0, \ i,j \in \mathbb Z} x^{i+j}$ would contain in its expansion $x^n$ exactly $n+1$ times because of stars and bars.

@mathphysicist9283 the coefficient for $x^n$ is the number of  solutions of  equation: $$x+y=n,\quad x,y=0,1,2,\cdots.$$ The key is $\binom{n+1}{1}=n+1$. Not only positive integer solutions!

How do you define $\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty a_ib_j$ ? The answer depends on that.

@RyszardSzwarc I used the symbol as a symplification for $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_i b_j$

Solution 1
Assume the  series $\sum a_n=:A$ and $\sum b_n=:B$  are convergent, at least one  is  absolutely convergent. Then
according to Merten's theorem 
their Cauchy product, i.e. the
series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left (\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}\right )$$ is convergent to $AB=\sum_i\sum_ja_ib_j.$
In the OP case $a_n=b_n=x^n$  and the corresponding series are absolutely convergent for $|x|<1.$ Moreover $$\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^nx^kx^{n-k}=(n+1)x^n$$ which implies the conclusion.
Solution 2 An elementary proof, because derivatives of only finite sums are applied, follows.
We have $$1+\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x^{n+1}={1-x^{N+1}\over 1-x}
$$ Applying the derivatives gives $$ \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(n+1)x^n=  {-(N+1)x^N(1-x)+1-x^{N+1}\over (1-x)^2}$$ When $N\to \infty $ we get $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(n+1)x^n={1\over (1-x)^2}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^ix^j$$ as $(N+1)x^N\to 0$ for $|x|<1.$

For $|x|<1$, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1+n)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^n;$$
$$\frac{1}{1-x}+x\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.$$
$$\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty x^{i+j}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^{i+j}
=\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i\cdot\frac1{1-x}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.$$
Here we use
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac1{1-x},\quad |x|<1,$$
several  times!

You don't even need to separate: $$(n+1)x^n=(x^{n+1})^\prime$$

Yes,  we can consider $$\frac{x}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n+1},\quad |x|<1,$$ and its derivative. There is no essential difference between these methods

@
Ryszard Szwarc
You can see my comment above in tha post!

I have just wanted to emphasize that your method is based on a highly nontrivial theorem.

Yes, you are right., but I give elementary proof in the comment, so here gives a different proof.

The comment, I mean, is under  the OP ' s post.

Stop now, there is no use to discuss the original theorem here.
